# SSRS- Fit PDF Export To One Page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am new to `SSRS`. I have created a report.

My report has four others reports in it. And I have set the page break. Page break works before displaying the new report.

So this way I get all four reports in separate tabs in excel. But now I want my report in `PDF` too. But after exporting to `PDF`, I get a **blank page** after each report.

Can I set the page break only for `EXCEL` and ignore if I export to `PDF`. Second my page doesn't fir while printing. In `PDF` it looks good. It is on single page. But when I try to print it shows half of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check now but look at Globals!RenderFormat (I think it's called that).

If you can set the page break on an expression then you can use this property to determine if you need the break of not.

Something like

```
=IIF(Globals.RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", False, True)
```

If this does not work, add a thin rectangle between each report, set the page breaks on that instead by setting the rectangle's page break properties. and then set the hidden property to the expression above. You will have to remove the existing page breaks.

Comment: I tried this. But did.t work. I unchecked the Page break from tablix properties. And then in the tablix properties ---> Page Break ---> Diseabled--> and wrote expression =IIF(Globals.RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", False, True)

Comment: I'll take a look when I get chance but not near a computer for a day or two

Answer (score 0):

It will happen sometimes. Try to change margins in `Report Properties`.

Body content size should not exceed Report page size.

`Body content size + margin size <= report width`

For Eg.

```
Body content size = 6 inch

Margin right = 1 inch

Margin Left 1 inch

Report width=8.5 inch
```

So, `6+1+1<=8.5` then report will render properly. Otherwise new empty page will come. Check below screen shot of report properties.

[image: Report Properties]

Overall `PDF` report size should match with **printer page setup**. Then it will print properly.

Comment: My body width was 28 inches and left and right margin are 0.5. so i set the report width to 29. after this blank page issue solved but print preview is not fixed. I have attached the screenshot  You can see the extra space at right side . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TGH813mUUVyyf--oXFfIZYNM5riOY9kg/view?usp=sharing    and the print preview screenshot is https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dJD2fHJbN8VlbnGrR_U40PkHuQkEmRJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You mentioned four sub report in your main report. Any one of the report might not be set properly in report margin. While PDF rendering will show blank space, If any one of the report had details with big size comparing others.